# Extract Usage Reports from Popularity Trends (Sharepoint Online) using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365

Days ago I was trying to retrieve the Usage Reports of all sites from my Sharepoint Online, but since we have too many sites, it would be difficult to get all of them by vising link after link downloading the .xlsx report. Then I started to work on a PowerShell script to extract those contents.

But for some reason, when my code is starting to download the file, it downloads the HTML code of the O365 login page instead. This suggests me that the application is losing session, because it was already connected to the site on the previous moment and suddenly I ended with a login page. Although I have no idea on how to fix this...

This is the code portion that attempts to downloads the usage report:

```
# Usage Reports for Prod 
$Usage       = $UsageGUID 

# set the file path and name 
$filename = $path + (Get-Variable $searchreport).Name + ".xlsx" 
$reportid = (Get-Variable $searchreport).Value

$TTNcontent = "javascript:ResetSpFormOnSubmitCalled();__doPostBack('__Page','ReportId=" + $reportid + "')"

# setup the WebRequest    
[net.httpWebRequest] $webRequest = [net.webRequest]::create($url)
$webRequest.Credentials = $SPOCredentials
$webRequest.CookieContainer = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer
$webRequest.Accept = "image/jpeg, application/x-ms-application, image/gif, application/xaml+xml, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, */*"    
$webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
$webRequest.Method = "POST"
$webRequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko"

$encodedContent = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($TTNcontent) 
$webRequest.ContentLength = $encodedContent.length 
$requestStream = $webRequest.GetRequestStream() 
$requestStream.Write($encodedContent, 0, $encodedContent.length) 
$requestStream.Close()

#The problem occurs on this step: Once GetResponse is fired, instead of getting the .xlsx as a response, it downloads the HTML of the O365 authentication screen
#My guess is that the application is losing the login session before the .GetResponse() but I don't know how/why...
[net.httpWebResponse] $resp = $webRequest.GetResponse();    
$rs = $resp.GetResponseStream();  
[System.IO.BinaryReader] $sr = New-Object System.IO.BinaryReader -argumentList $rs; 
[byte[]]$results = $sr.ReadBytes(10000000);

# write the file 
Set-Content $filename $results -enc byte
```

Here is the full code file:
[GetUsageReports_SPOnline.ps1](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AuGPTf1Es76773SEOMX1z3nDJ4xM)

Any ideas or suggestions...?

Thanks in advance :)

Marco